# LVM Thin pool performance with NVMe

Tags: linux, performance, lvm, nvme, thin-provisioning

I have 24 Samsung PM1733 7.68 TB and a server platform Gigabyte R282-Z94 with 2x 7702 64cores AMD EPYC. OS: Oracle Linux 8.6, 5.4.17-2136.311.6.el8uek.x86_64

I need this server for testing so I have to use a thin pool in my environment (i need snaps). I also use LVM because I have used it before. But I tried ZFS and could not get better results.

The main question sounds like this: **How to get maximum performance using thin pools.**

What I do:

`vgcreate vg1 /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1 /dev/nvme3n1 /dev/nvme4n1`

`lvcreate -n thin_pool_1 -L 20T vg1 /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1 /dev/nvme3n1 -i 4 -I 4`

-i4 for striping between all disks, -I4 strip size. Also I tried 8, 16, 32... In my setup I cant find a big difference.

`lvcreate -n pool_meta -L 15G vg1 /dev/nvme4n1`

`lvconvert --type thin-pool --poolmetadata vg1/pool_meta vg1/thin_pool_1`

`lvchange -Zn vg1/thin_pool_1` - for disable zeroing.

`lvcreate -V 15000G --thin -n data vg1/thin_pool_1`

After that I create a load using the FIO with parameters:

`fio --filename=/dev/mapper/vg1-data --rw=randwrite --bs=4k --name=test --numjobs=32 --iodepth=32 --random_generator=tausworthe64 --numa_cpu_nodes=0 --direct=1`

I only get 40k iops, while one drive at the same load easily gives 130k iops.

I don't understand what I'm missing when configuring the system.